# C function not callable

Tags: c, gcc, x86, nasm, inline-assembly

I am writing some simple c code that i try to call from assembly (nasm). However before actually using the code in assembly there are already errors i do not understand.

This is the code:

```c
void start();
void print();

void start()
{
    print();
}

void print()
{
    asm("mov si, 0");
    asm("mov ah, 0");
    asm("mov al, 0");
    asm("int 0x27");
}
```

Decompiling the code leads to the following:

```
00000200  55                push bp
00000201  89E5              mov bp,sp
00000203  83EC08            sub sp,byte +0x8
00000206  E80200            call word 0x20b
00000209  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000020B  C9                leave
0000020C  C3                ret
0000020D  55                push bp
0000020E  89E5              mov bp,sp
00000210  66BE0000B400      mov esi,0xb40000
00000216  B000              mov al,0x0
00000218  CD27              int 0x27
0000021A  5D                pop bp
0000021B  C3                ret
```

In line 206 the call for function "print()" will result in a jump to position 20B, but this is the exit procedure of the "start()" function. If the call was correct it should jump to position 20D shouldn't it?

I don't know what i am doing wrong with such a little bit of code - i am not used to c programming.

By the way, i compile and link the c code with the following command line options on windows:

```
gcc ccode.c --freestanding -masm=intel -c -o ccode.o
ld -o ccode.bin ccode.o
```

Comment: Minor, yet important point: That's not "line 206" but "offset 206". In your output that's the 4th line.

Comment: Do experiments on https://godbolt.org/

Comment: If you are using a modern GCC you need to pass `-m16` (or add `asm(".code16gcc")` to the top of all your C files that you wish to compile so they have a chance to work in real mode. The next problem is that the tool you used to dump the code - appears to have been told to dump the 32-bit code you wrote as 16-bit code which is why you get bizarre decodings like `add [bx+si],al`

Comment: I don't recommend GCC for doing 16-bit code unless you understand all the issues regarding how inline assembly works, and the pitfalls of using the `-m16` option.

Comment: I can tell you are compiling on a 32-bit system given the decoded instructions suggest the GCC compiler wasn't producing 64-bit prefixes.

Comment: I'd be curious what tool you used to disassemble the code (appears to be `ndisasm`). One thing is that `ld -o ccode.bin ccode.o` won't generate a binary file called `ccode.bin`. It will generate an ELF file called `ccode.bin`. If you want to generate a binary file you will need to specify an origin point, and that you want binary output. Something like `gcc ccode.c -ffreestanding -masm=intel -c -o ccode.o`  `ld --oformat=binary -Ttext=0x200 -o ccode.bin ccode.o`

Comment: I'm also curious in what environment you intend to run this code? In DOS? As a bootloader? Or are you trying to run this on Linux or Windows? Something else (like your own OS or some academic OS)? `Int 0x27` is not an interrupt I'm familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: I added asm(".code16gcc") to the c file and now it works for me. Thanks alot. 

And yes you are right, i am using ndisasm and did not pass the -b 16/32 option. After using this option the assembly code is more readable.

"ld --oformat=binary -Ttext=0x200 -o ccode.bin ccode.o" I will also try that, thanks.

"I'm also curious in what environment you intend to run this code?" It's an mini os i am working on for academic purpos, so far totally written in nasm but i wanted to try some c too. Int 0x27 is an interrupt i implemented for easier printing of strings.

Comment: Bare separate asm statements like what you have in `print` are not valid usage. Nothing preserves the values you load into registers from one asm statement to the next. You need a single asm statement with all of them in it, and proper register clobber constraints unless you save/restore all registers you plan to use on your own inside it.

Comment: It looks like you compiled 32-bit code and then disassembled it as if it were 16-bit.  So your disassembler thought the default operand-size was 16, but the code was generated assuming default operand-size = 32.

That's why `mov si, 0` had a `66` operand-size prefix, and decoded as `mov esi, 0xb40000`.  Decoding that instruction consumed the 2-byte `mov ah,0` as part of a 32-bit (instead of 16-bit) immediate.

Comment: If your question is answered by some hints in the comments, please write an answer and mark it as such. You will save us all a lot of time looking at this question that might be no longer open. You know that you can answer your own question, don't you?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling the code to 16 bit worked for me, thank you!

If you are using a modern GCC you need to pass -m16 (or add asm(".code16gcc") to the top of all your C files that you wish to compile so they have a chance to work in real mode. The next problem is that the tool you used to dump the code - appears to have been told to dump the 32-bit code you wrote as 16-bit code which is why you get bizarre decodings like add [bx+si],al

Comment: GCC never had `-m16` as the default.  You can omit the word "modern"; AFAIK GCC was never ported to 8086, only to i386.  `-m16` is still just an afterthought, with type sizes still being mostly 32-bit.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I used modern in my original comment because when the experimental `.code16gcc` option was added to binutils gnu assembler (as), there was no corresponding `-m16` for GCC. GCC's `-m16` option only came years later. So it is possible to find versions of old GCC that don't support `-m16` but have an AS that supports`.code16gcc`. At the time of my comment I didn't know what version `-m16` was added. As for an ia16 version of GCC, there is a fork of that here (unstable and experimental): https://github.com/tkchia/gcc-ia16 . That version of GCC creates strictly 16-bit code.

Comment: `-m16` was finally added to GCC in 4.9.0 (April of 2014) according to the [release notes](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-4.9/changes.html). GNU assembler apparently supported `.code16gcc` as far back as 2001: https://lwn.net/Articles/241399/